# Docker stack deploy cannot deploy service to different node in swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am trying to deploy the application on multiple instances. On master node. after deployed application running the only master node. cannot deploy service different node in the docker swarm cluster.
here my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"

services:

  mydb:
    image: localhost:5000/mydb-1
    environment:
      TZ: "Asia/Colombo"
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
    volumes:
      - /root/data/cdb:/var/lib/cassandra
      - /root/logs/cdb:/var/log/cassandra
```

command `docker service scale  mydb-1_mydb=5`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                 NAMES
7fxxxxxxxx7        localhost:5000/mydb-1:latest   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   16 seconds ago      Up 5 seconds        7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp           mydb-1_mydb.2.q77i258vn2xynlgein9s7tdpb
34fcxxxx14bd        localhost:5000/mydb-1:latest   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   16 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds        7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp           mydb-1_mydb.1.s2mzitj8yzb0zo7spd3dmpo1j
9axxxx1efb        localhost:5000/mydb-1:latest   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   16 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds        7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp           mydb-1_mydb.3.zgyev3p4qdg7hf7h67oeedutr
f14xxxee59        localhost:5000/mydb-1:latest   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   16 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds        7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp           mydb-1_mydb.4.r0themodonzzr1izdbnppd5bi
e3xxx16d        localhost:5000/mydb-1:latest   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   16 seconds ago      Up 6  seconds        7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp           mydb-1_mydb.5.bdebi4
```

all running only master-node. Does anyone know the issue?

Comment: What `docker node ls` returns?

Comment: yes. showing all node active state

Comment: `ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
pcmabdsjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd *   beta-master         Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.5
iptx66h4xxxxxxxxxxxxxz820     beta-node-1         Ready               Active                                  19.03.5
kqylfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3b11k     beta-node-2         Ready               Active                                  19.03.5` @samthegolden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I find the issue and fixed.

```
volumes:
      - /root/data/cdb:/var/lib/cassandra
      - /root/logs/cdb:/var/log/cassandra
```

If you bind mount a host path into your service’s containers, the path must exist on every swarm node.

```
docker service scale zkr_zkr=2
```

after scale-up service running my node

```
root@beta-node-1:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                    NAMES
f9bxxx15861        localhost:5000/zookeeper:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes       2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 8080/tcp   zkr_zkr.3.qpr8qp5y
01dxxxx64bc        localhost:5000/zookeeper:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes       2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 8080/tcp   zkr_zkr.1.g2uee5j
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image appears to be locally built with a name that cannot be resolved in other nodes (`localhost:5000/mydb-1`). In swarm, images should be pushed to a registry, and that registry needs to be accessible by all nodes. You can run your own registry service on your own node, there's a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry), or you can push to docker hub. If the registry is private, you also need to perform a `docker login` on the node running the stack deploy and include registry credentials in that deploy, e.g.

```
docker stack deploy -c compose.yml --with-registry-auth stack-name
```

Comment: `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                    NAMES

dbxxxx42f9        registry:2                        "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   20 hours ago         Up 2 hours          5000/tcp                                 registry.1.to4l4xj7kso44qr5dz8fj1fr5
`   actually this image here my local private registry  `root@beta-node-2:~# curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["mydb-1"]}
` my node

Comment: logging in and pulling the images from hub did that trick to me